# Comma after lifespan?

Tags: commas

Should there be a comma after the lifespan of Alexander the Great?

When thinking of world conquerers, Alexander the Great (July 356 –June 323 BC), comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using parentheses, you put a comma after the parentheses only if you'd put a comma after the word preceding the parentheses.

In this case, you wouldn't put a comma after Alexander the Great if you didn't include the dates in parentheses, so you shouldn't put a comma after the parentheses.